# start Apache NiFi in background on windows10

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using Apache NiFi 1.11.4 on Windows-10

I am able to run it using run-nifi.bat (Foreground)

But i want to run it in background.
As per Apache docs we should use command "bin>nifi.sh start" to run in background.

But when i run this command i get below error[image]

Comment: there is a header above this line in documentation: "For Linux/Mac OS X users". There is no official way to run nifi in background or as a service under Windows. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/getting-started.html#starting-nifi

Comment: ohk Thanks for this info.